# Excel VBA Worksheet Change Event assigned

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel 2007, I understand that I can create worksheet_change event on the worksheet it's created.

But how do I assign a global sub change events to a newly created worksheet?

e.g.

```
Public Sub DataChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' this will check and see if the user or operator has change the column field
  ' if they fill in "X", mark the whole row to red color
  ' otherwise leave it black
  Dim KeyCells As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row
  Set KeyCells = Range("L2:L" & LastRow)

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
    Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "X" Or Target.Value = "x" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Font.color = vbRed
    Else
        Target.EntireRow.Font.color = vbBlack
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Then in a separate sub procedure in Module1...

```
Public Sub CreateWorkSheet() 
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Sheets.Add
  ws.Name = "Test1"
  ' Here where I want to set the event but I do not know the syntax
  ' ws.OnChange = DataChange

  Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub
```

I'm used to assign events on the fly when creating controls (C#/WPF/Pascal), so I figured there would be one in Excel world. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you create a blank worksheet, add code to the worksheet's code sheet and hide it, you can copy it or use it as a template for future new worksheets and the code will follow. Alternately you can opt for a Workbook_SheetChange event handler.

Comment: Question, how does Excel knows which worksheet to run the macros? I thought it was limited to only the selected worksheet it's focus? In this case, the code to update cell was hidden, but how does the code continue to run on another worksheet? Sounds like a override function happening in Excel?

Also the problem with this one is that I may want to only use the sub on certain worksheet instead of all.

Comment: A Worksheet_Change has only Target passed to it; a Workbook_SheetChange has Sh for the worksheet and Target. I like to use a Select Case to parse the worksheet name.

Comment: ... and yes, your DataChange will require proper parent worksheet referencing for all range and cell calls but tbh, those should have been there from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Jeeped, probably the easiest way would be to copy the sheet that already had the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` code behind it, but there is also another way, if you place the following code under `ThisWorkbook`, whenever a new sheet is created it will add the desired code behind it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Code = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "MsgBox ""your code here""" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(NewSheet.Name).CodeModule
    NextLine = .CountOfLines + 1
    .InsertLines NextLine, Code
    End With
End Sub
```

The drawback here is that the Trust Settings for Macros would need to be changed by clicking on the `Trust access to the VBA project object model`:

[image]

**EDIT:**

You could also copy code from one worksheet to another using a similar method:

```
Sub test()
Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim CodePaste As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Long

Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines
'Use this line to erase all code that might already be in sheet2
'If CodePaste.CountOfLines > 1 Then CodePaste.DeleteLines 1, CodePaste.CountOfLines

CodePaste.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. This looks like explicitly creating subs on the fly rather than assigning pre-existing subs. Much more complex this way but that's a great alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Skibur I've edited my answer to include a way to copy code from one worksheet to another, hope this helps. :)

Comment: Even better! Thank you so much for your answer. I did mention that I wanted to apply this rule to only the newly created worksheet. So far this is the best solution.

Comment: @Skibur, another note, when referencing the Sheet name it should be the CodeName of the Sheet and not the tab Name, which you can get by using something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").CodeName`, hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Xabier Huh, man, I owe you one! The use of Name instead of CodeName leads to undefined behaviour and I wasted a couple of hours troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the last @Jeeped's suggestion

place this code in `ThisWorkbook` code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    DataChange Target ' this sub will be called at any change of any worksheet passing the chenged range
End Sub
```

then place this in the same code pane or in any other Module

```
Public Sub DataChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' this will check and see if the user or operator has change the column field
  ' if they fill in "X", mark the whole row to red color
  ' otherwise leave it black
  Dim KeyCells As Range
  Set KeyCells = Range("L2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then Target.EntireRow.Font.color = IIf(UCase(Target.Value2) = "X", vbRed, vbBlack)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer, but how does it assign to specific worksheets?

Comment: The `Workbook_SheetChange` event will fire when _any_ worksheet in the workbook is changed so it isn't assigned to a specific worksheet but to all worksheets.  The sheet being changed is held in the `sh` argument and the cells that were changed are held in the `Target` argument.